# Change text in button (gridview) using if else

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one button to change based on the page. I have 3 page which is confirmed, pending and rejected.

On confirmed and rejected the text inside the button is same but different for pending. How can change the word in the button. The button placed in the grid view.

Below the code in aspx file:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>Actions</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="lnkbtnInfo" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' CommandName="Detail" /></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How can i do in the cs file, to use the if else.
For rejected and confirmed page, the button is "view" and pending page is "review"

Comment: Have you want to change button text in codebehind? Which variable/property used to determine "confirmed", "rejected" and "pending" state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my answer that works on my situation:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Button name = (Button)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lnkbtnInfo"); // find control from your button ID
            Label status= (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl ("lblStatus");
            if (status.Text == "Complete" || status.Text == "Rejected" || status.Text == "Cancelled" || 
                status.Text == "Returned" || status.Text == "UserRejected")//refer to confirm and reject order
            {
                name.Text = "View";
            }

            else // refer to pending order
            {
                name.Text = "review";
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured that you need to use `RowDataBound` event handler on gridview and create if statement based on button's `CommandArgument` state:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Button status = (Button)GridView.Rows[i].FindControl("lnkbtnInfo"); // find control from your button ID

        String state = status.CommandArgument.ToString(); // assume the value given by Eval data binding
        if (state.Equals("confirmed") || state.Equals("rejected"))
        {
            status.Text = "view";
        }
        else // if (state.Equals("pending"))
        {
            status.Text = "review";
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [Change button text in asp:gridview based on cell value C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745275/change-button-text-in-aspgridview-based-on-cell-value-c-sharp)

Comment: did i need to change in text="" part in aspx file?

Comment: Tetsuya, the command argument actually refer to id which is order id and it will show the status based on the order id created by user.is there any way to hard code the button name?

Comment: You can set directly `Text="view"` in asp:Button, however if you want to change it programmatically from gridview's cell value when page state is pending, use proper `CommandArgument` to pass page state value, then set string variable `state` from it.

Comment: thanks for the idea, i have modify it a bot as the eval data binding not refer  the status, it refer to id order..refer to my answer above

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is use `Eval` with ternary for changing Button Text on .aspx page,

[Ternary Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ty67wk28.aspx)  syntax

`(your condition) ? "if true value":" if false value";`

Here is Example " if you want to check that your **'Id'** is 3 then Button Text should be View else It should be Review."

```
<asp:Button ID="lnkbtnInfo" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text='<%# ((int)Eval("Id") == 3) ? "view":"Review" %>' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' CommandName="Detail" />
```